# Preserving whitespaces from the XSL stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace, xalan

I'm trying to convert this XML :-

```
<list>
  <unit>
    <data1>a</data1>
    <data2>b</data2>
    <data3>c</data3>
  </unit>
</list>
```

to this :-

```
<list>
  <unit>
    <category1>
      <data1>a</data1>
      <data2>b</data2>
    </category1>
    <category2>
      <data3>c</data3>
    </category2>
  </unit>
</list>
```

using XSL. I'm using the following XSL:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:s="some_namespace">


<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//s:unit" xml:space="preserve">
  <xsl:copy>
  <category1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./s:data1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./s:data2"/>
  </category1>
  <category2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./s:data3"/>
  </category2>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, this preserves the indentation within  but completely messes it up w.r.t. list. This is what I get :-

```
  <list>
<unit>
  <category1>
    <data1>a</data1>
    <data2>b</data2>
  </category1>
  <category2>
    <data3>c</data3>
  </category2>
</unit>
  </list>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you searching for? Indentation?

Comment: yes. indentation in the output xml.

Comment: This is implementation - dependent. Most processors produce good indentation when `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` is used -- together or without `<xsl:strip-space select="*"/>` . Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Xalan-c on red hat el5 directly from the yum package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

I think that one shouldn't be messing with the default indentation of the XSLT processor.

Most often the combination of `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` and `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` is sufficient for getting good indentation.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="unit">
  <unit>
      <category1>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(position() >2)]"/>
      </category1>
      <category2>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() >2]"/>
      </category2>
  </unit>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<list>
      <unit>
        <data1>a</data1>
        <data2>b</data2>
        <data3>c</data3>
      </unit>
</list>
```

**Produces the wanted, well-indented result**:

```
<list>
  <unit>
    <category1>
      <data1>a</data1>
      <data2>b</data2>
    </category1>
    <category2>
      <data3>c</data3>
    </category2>
  </unit>
</list>
```

**This same result is produced when the transformation is run with any of the following seven XSLT processors**:

- AltovaXML (XML-SPY).
- .NET XslCompiledTransform.
- .NET XslTransform.
- Saxon 6.5.4.
- Saxon 9.1.05 (XSLT 2.0 processor).
- XQSharp/XMLPrime (XSLT 2.0 processor).
- AltovaXml (for XSLT 2.0).

**The case with MSXML3/4/6 is more complicated** -- these XSLT processors' indentation consists just of a new-line character, so every element is on a new line, but appears at the start of the line.

For these XSLT processors I use the following two-pass processing, the first pass being the above transformation and the second applies to the result of the first pass **[one of the XML pretty-printers](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/pretty.html#d8625e19)** proposed by Nikolai Grigoriev and available in the **[XSLT FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/index.html)** site maintained by **[Dave Pawson](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output method="xml"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="indent-increment" select="'   '" />

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1/*" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="unit">
  <unit>
      <category1>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(position() >2)]"/>
      </category1>
      <category2>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() >2]"/>
      </category2>
  </unit>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="pass2">
     <xsl:param name="indent" select="'&#xA;'"/>

     <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2">
         <xsl:with-param name="indent"
              select="concat($indent, $indent-increment)"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
       <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="pass2">
     <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- WARNING: this is dangerous. Handle with care -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)='']" mode="pass2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed on the same (provided) XML document (above), the produced result has the desired indentation**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<list>
   <unit>
      <category1>
         <data1>a
         </data1>
         <data2>b
         </data2>
      </category1>
      <category2>
         <data3>c
         </data3>
      </category2>
   </unit>
</list>
```

These are all XSLT processors I have on my computers. I suggest to try the last transformation -- the chances are that it will produce the wanted results with Xalan-C.

**Do note**:

The last transformation uses an MSXML - specific extension function xxx:node-set(), belonging to an MSXML - specific namespace:

```
xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

**For Xalan this needs to be replaced with**:

```
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
```

**or, in case EXSLT isn't supported, then the native Xalan namespace**:

```
xmlns:ext="http://xml.apache.org/xalan
```

In this last case, the call to the `ext:node-set()` function must be replaced with a call to `ext:nodeset()` (note the missing dash):

```
 <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:nodeset($vrtfPass1)"/>
```